# Image and text coming in same line

Tags: html, css

I'm designing a small webpage with image and content in it. 
 In our app we have 2 modes of reading, Scroll mode and Book mode. In book mode, everything looks fine.
 But when i switch to scroll mode, the image and data come to appear on the same line. please let me know how can i fix this. 
Below is my code.

```
<div class="pgnfigure">
                    <img alt="" align="left" class="headImg" src="18.jpg" assetid="er:#18">
                </div>
  <div class="para_Grey">savbdsbdfgfdbftrhfgnfvnhtykjmytjgtfnhghnfghsavbdsbdfgfdbftrhfgnfvnhtykjmytjgtfnhghnfghsavbdsbdfgfdbftrhfgnfvnhtykjmytjgtfnhghnfghsavbdsbdfgfdbftrhfgnfvnhtykjmytjgtfnhghnfghsavbdsbdfgfdbftrhfgnfvnhtykjmytjgtfnhghnfghsavbdsbdfgfdbftrhfgnfvnhtykjmytjgtfnhghnfghsavbdsbdfgfdbftrhfgnfvnhtykjmytjgtfnhghnfghsavbdsbdfgfdbftrhfgnfvnhtykjmytjgtfnhghnfghsavbdsbdfgfdbftrhfgnfvnhtykjmytjgtfnhghnfgh</div>
```

And CSS

```
 .pgnfigure {
    padding-bottom: 10em;
}
.para_Grey{
  text-align: justify;
}
```

I cant produce a scroll view css, since this is designed as per book view.
here is a working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/6vkhxd8f/

Comment: I am struggling to understand what the problem is, i understand you want to display text below your image, but in your fiddle it works just fine, this probably is caused by dependencies you didn't include.

Comment: What is it that you want? What is the expected behaviour? You are using a local image in the fiddle. Could you upload it somewhere and update your fiddle? 
Create a StackOverflow snippet so that users don't have to go to another page to see your issue in action.

Comment: What exactly is the question...? [This](https://jsfiddle.net/Zekedran/6vkhxd8f/7/) already has the text below the image. Is the question how to make that text vertically scrollable (since it is in the scroll view or scroll mode)?

Answer (score 0):

```css
.para_Grey{
  display:block;
  text-align: justify;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think everything just works fine as long as you don't want to break words [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Zekedran/6vkhxd8f/5/). However if you want to break words then just add `word-wrap: break-word` to your div as in [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Zekedran/6vkhxd8f/6/)

Or if you're facing problems with width of the div, and some scroll-issues, you may have to add `max-width: 100%;` and sometimes if scroll doesn't work yuy may have to add `overflow-y:auto;`

Answer (score 0):

you can use another div in between both div

```
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

it will take another div in next line